# What forms can a function take such its derivative is greater than or equal to the function?

Tags: calculus

Following this question and discussion recently
[Is the derivative of a function bigger or equal to $e^x$ will always be bigger or equal to the function ?!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208313/is-the-derivative-of-a-function-bigger-or-equal-to-ex-will-always-be-bigger-o)

I decided to look at the  different forms that a function which is *always* less than its derivative takes, so instead of looking at when $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \ge 1$. I restated the question to this.

Let $g(x)$ be a function such that $g(x) \ge 1\space  \forall x$ then solving the following the inequality will give us the functions we need.
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = g(x)$$

Solving that differential equation you get that $f(x)$ takes on the form (where $k$ is a constant and $g(x) \ge 1 \space \forall x$)
$$f(x) = ke^{\int g(x)dx}$$

My question is do all functions that have derivatives greater than the function itself have this form or am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry I misread the post

Comment: No worries, ill edit the post to make it more clear for everyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking for a simple criterion for a positive function $f$, which is equivalent to the differential inequality $f'(x)\geq f(x)$ for all $x$. One can say the following:

A differentiable function $f:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}_{>0}$ satisfies $f'(x)\geq f(x)$ for all $x$ **iff** the function $$g(x):={f(x)\over e^x}$$
is increasing.

*Proof.* One has $g'(x)=\bigl(f'(x)-f(x)\bigr)e^{-x}$, and this is $\geq0$ for all $x$ iff $f'(x)\geq f(x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I found this condition, that probably is very similar to yours, except in the concretion of the constant $k$. Integrating the inequality from a point $x_0$ of the domain of $f$,

\begin{align}
\int_{x_0}^xdx \leq \int_{x_0}^x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx \iff x - x_0 \leq \ln\frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)} \iff f(x) \geq f(x_0)e^{x - x_0}.
\end{align}

However, about the implication $\Leftarrow$ of the first step, where I integrate both sides, I think that it's not true in general, so maybe here you have some constraint for $f$.

Comment: Yes you are right this doesn't work in general as the choice for $x_0$ should be one where $f(x_0) = 0$ as it then causes a lot of problems! Also  this is very closely related to the question I linked in mine. I think itll be helpful if you read the discussion there.

Answer (score 0):

What if $g(x) = h(x,f(x))$ ? The solution is not the most general case.

I think the best thing you can get is a general differential equation.
A more general case is to take
$$ \frac{f'}{f} = 1+ g(x,f(x) , f'(x))$$
for some non-negative function $g$.